# valgrind : Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value using strlen() strncat()

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind, strlen

I am writing a grep program in C. In order to determine if the current line received should be printed to the screen, i use a function called **reportLineMatchRec**. 
in this function i use another function named **updateConExpWithStr2** to parse one of the strings used in reportLineMatchRec(). 
unfortunately, i keep getting valgrind errors saying there is uninitialized value being used inside this function, when using strlen() and strncat(), eventhough i initialized all values.

**update:** i updated the functions `updateConExpWithStr1()` and `updateConExpWithStr2()` so the gcc warning is gone and now i'm getting a single valgrind error (also updated below). i added to the valgrind check --track-origins=yes parameter which points out that the source for initialization problem is in the malloc inside `fillRoundBrackets()` inside **commandParser** module (added below). I still can't solve the problem.

### the code:

#### the structs:

```
typedef enum {REGULAR, POINT, ROUND_BRACKETS, BRACKETS} partClassifier;

union expressionPartInfo {
    char xy[2];
    char *str1OrStr2;
    char regularChar;
}expressionPartInfo;

typedef struct partInExpression
{
    union expressionPartInfo expressionPartInfo ;
    partClassifier partClassifier;
} partInExpression;

typedef struct parsedCommandStruct 
{
    char *expressionToSearch;
    char *origExpressionToSearch;
    char *concatenatedExpression;
    int lengthOfOrigExpression;
    int numOfExpressionParts;
    bool a;
    int aNum;
    bool b;
    bool c;
    bool i;
    bool n;
    bool v;
    bool x;
    bool E;
    struct partInExpression *arrayOfExpressionParts;
} parsedCommandStruct;
```

#### upadted matchInLine.c relevant functions:

```
void updateConExpWithStr1(parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand,  char **endOfString, int partIndex, char **orPtr,
        int *str1size,char **orPtrcopy){
    char *copyStr1OrStr2 = malloc(parsedCommand->lengthOfOrigExpression+1);
    strcpy(copyStr1OrStr2, parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2);
    *endOfString = parsedCommand->concatenatedExpression+strlen(parsedCommand->concatenatedExpression);
    *orPtr = strstr(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2, "|");
    *orPtrcopy=(*orPtr)+1;
    **orPtr = '\0';
    *str1size = strlen(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2);
    strcat(parsedCommand->concatenatedExpression, parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].
    expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2);
    strcpy(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2, copyStr1OrStr2);
    free(copyStr1OrStr2);
}

void updateConExpWithStr2(parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand, int partIndex, char **orPtr,
                          int const*str1size, char **endOfString, char **orPtrcopy){
    int str2size=0;
    **endOfString = '\0';
    str2size = strlen(*orPtrcopy);
    strncat(parsedCommand->concatenatedExpression, *orPtrcopy, str2size);
}


void reportLineMatchRecE(int partIndex, lineInText *currentLineToCheck, parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand,
        int *linesAfterMatchCounterPtr, int *prevLinesCounter, int *matchFlag){
    int j=0; char *orPtr = NULL; int str1size = 0; char *endOfString = NULL; char *orPtrcopy = NULL;
    while(partIndex < parsedCommand->numOfExpressionParts){
        if(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].partClassifier == REGULAR) {
            updateConExpWithRegChr(parsedCommand, &partIndex);
        }
        else if (parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].partClassifier == POINT){
            for (j = ASCII_LOWEST_CHAR; j < ASCII_HIGHEST_CHAR+1; j++) {
                updateConExpWithChr(j, parsedCommand, &endOfString);
                reportLineMatchRec(partIndex+1, currentLineToCheck, parsedCommand, linesAfterMatchCounterPtr,
                        prevLinesCounter, matchFlag);
                *endOfString='\0';
            }
            return;
        }
        else if(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].partClassifier == BRACKETS){
            for (j = parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.xy[0];
            j < parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.xy[1]+1; j++) {
                updateConExpWithChr(j, parsedCommand, &endOfString);
                reportLineMatchRec(partIndex+1, currentLineToCheck, parsedCommand, linesAfterMatchCounterPtr,
                        prevLinesCounter, matchFlag);
                *endOfString='\0';
            }
            return;
        }
        else if(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].partClassifier == ROUND_BRACKETS){
            updateConExpWithStr1(parsedCommand, &endOfString, partIndex, &orPtr ,&str1size, &orPtrcopy);
            reportLineMatchRec(partIndex+1, currentLineToCheck, parsedCommand, linesAfterMatchCounterPtr,
                    prevLinesCounter, matchFlag);
            updateConExpWithStr2(parsedCommand, partIndex, &orPtr, &str1size, &endOfString, &orPtrcopy);
            reportLineMatchRec(partIndex+1, currentLineToCheck, parsedCommand, linesAfterMatchCounterPtr,
                    prevLinesCounter, matchFlag);
            return;
        }
    }
    if(partIndex == parsedCommand->numOfExpressionParts){
        strcpy(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch, parsedCommand->concatenatedExpression);
        reportLineMatch(currentLineToCheck, *parsedCommand, linesAfterMatchCounterPtr, prevLinesCounter, matchFlag);
        return;
    }
}
```

#### commandParser.c relevant functions:

```
int fillRoundBrackets(parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand, int indexOfParts, char *str1OrStr2){
    parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[indexOfParts].partClassifier = ROUND_BRACKETS;
    char *placeOfClosingBracket = strstr(str1OrStr2, ")");
    int str12Size = placeOfClosingBracket-str1OrStr2 - 1;
    parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[indexOfParts].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2 = NULL;
    parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[indexOfParts].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2 = malloc(200);//str12Size+1);
    strncpy(parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[indexOfParts].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2, str1OrStr2+1, str12Size);
    return str12Size+1;
}

void buildArrayOfExpressionParts(parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand){
    int numOfParts = computeNumOfParts(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch); int i=0, indexOfParts=0;
    parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts = NULL;
    parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts = malloc(numOfParts * sizeof(partInExpression));
    for(i=0; i<(int)strlen(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch); i++)
    {
        if(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i] == '.')
        {
            parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[indexOfParts].partClassifier = POINT;
        }
        else if(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i] == '[')
        {
            fillBrackets(parsedCommand, indexOfParts, parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i+1],
                    parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i+3]);
            i=i+4;
        }
        else if(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i] == '(') {
            parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[indexOfParts].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2 = NULL;
            i = i + fillRoundBrackets(parsedCommand, indexOfParts, parsedCommand->expressionToSearch + i);
        }
        else if(parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i] == '\\')
        {
            fillRegularChar(parsedCommand, indexOfParts, parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i+1]);
            i=i+1;
        }
        else {
            fillRegularChar(parsedCommand, indexOfParts, parsedCommand->expressionToSearch[i]);
        }
        indexOfParts++;
    }
}

void createAndFillCommand(int argc, char *argv[], parsedCommandStruct **parsedCommand) {
    int indexOfExpressionArg = INITIALIZED_VALUE;
    indexOfExpressionArg = searchExpressionArgumentIndex(argc, argv);
    *parsedCommand = (parsedCommandStruct *) malloc(sizeof(struct parsedCommandStruct));
    initializeCommandArgs(parsedCommand);
    (*parsedCommand)->expressionToSearch =  (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[indexOfExpressionArg])+1);
    strcpy((*parsedCommand)->expressionToSearch, argv[indexOfExpressionArg]);
    (*parsedCommand)->origExpressionToSearch =  (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[indexOfExpressionArg])+1);
    strcpy((*parsedCommand)->origExpressionToSearch, argv[indexOfExpressionArg]);
    (*parsedCommand)->lengthOfOrigExpression = strlen((*parsedCommand)->expressionToSearch); // delete?
    (*parsedCommand)->numOfExpressionParts = computeNumOfParts((*parsedCommand)->expressionToSearch);
    updateArgumentsOfCommandStruct(argc, argv, *parsedCommand);
    if((*parsedCommand)->E){
        buildArrayOfExpressionParts(*parsedCommand);
        (*parsedCommand)->concatenatedExpression = (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[indexOfExpressionArg])+1);
        strcpy((*parsedCommand)->concatenatedExpression, "");
    }

}
```

#### main.c:

```
void receiveAndExecute(parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand, FILE **stream)
{
    ssize_t lineSize = INITIALIZED_VALUE; int matchFlag = 0;
    lineInText *currentLine = NULL;
    int lineIndex = FIRST_LINE_INDEX, counterForC = INITIALIZED_VALUE,
    linesAfterMatchCounter = INITIALIZED_VALUE, sumOfBytes = INITIALIZED_VALUE, prevLinesCounter = INITIALIZED_VALUE;
    currentLine = malloc(sizeof *currentLine);
    initializeCurrentLine(currentLine);

    while (1)
    {
        readLine(stream, &lineSize, currentLine);
        FillLineStruct(currentLine, lineIndex, sumOfBytes);
        sumOfBytes = (int)lineSize + sumOfBytes;
        lineIndex++;
        initializeConcatinateExp(parsedCommand);
        if(lineSize<0)
            break;
        reportLineMatchRec(0, currentLine, parsedCommand, &linesAfterMatchCounter, &prevLinesCounter, &matchFlag);
        printLineToOutput(currentLine, parsedCommand, &counterForC, false, &linesAfterMatchCounter,
                &prevLinesCounter, &matchFlag);
    }
    printLineToOutput(currentLine, parsedCommand, &counterForC, true, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    freeLine(&currentLine);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    parsedCommandStruct *parsedCommand = NULL;
    FILE *filePtr = NULL;
    bool useFile = false;
    useFile = isUsingFile(argc, argv);
    createAndFillCommand(argc, argv, &parsedCommand);

    if (useFile)
    {
        filePtr = openFile(argv[argc-1]);
        receiveAndExecute(parsedCommand, &filePtr);
        fclose(filePtr);
    }
    else
    {
        receiveAndExecute(parsedCommand, &stdin);
    }
    freeParsedCommandStruct(parsedCommand);
    free(parsedCommand);
    return 0;
}
```

#### updated valgrind report

```
==7832== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7832==    at 0x4C2E1EB: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7832==    by 0x401BF7: updateConExpWithStr1 (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x401F48: reportLineMatchRecE (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x4020A4: reportLineMatchRec (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x402280: receiveAndExecute (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x402377: main (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==7832==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7832==    by 0x40108C: fillRoundBrackets (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x401218: buildArrayOfExpressionParts (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x40142D: createAndFillCommand (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==    by 0x40233B: main (in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/nadavbarkol/c_lab/ex2/my_grep)
==7832==
```

Comment: **even though i initialized all values.** Obviously, you didn't really initialize `parsedCommand` properly. But you didn't post the code that supposedly initialized it, so we can't tell what you did wrong.

Comment: I see that you're passing the structure by value, not with a pointer. If you do that when you call the function that's supposed to initialize it, it will just initialize the local copy, not the caller's variable.

Comment: Not excited about passing the struct by value, and you're calling `strlen(parsedCommand.concatenatedExpression);` without seeing if there's a valid pointer there. `concatenatedExpression` only gets a value conditionally.

Comment: `char *argv[] ... (*parsedCommand)->concatenatedExpression = (char *) malloc(sizeof(argv[indexOfExpressionArg])+1);` is suspicious.  `sizeof(argv[indexOfExpressionArg])` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: i changed my code so now its passing a pointer to the original parsedCommandStruct parsedCommand all the way to updateConExpWithStr2() but i still get the same errors from valgrind.

Comment: you are right about the sizeof(). i switched it to strlen() but it still don't solve the errors from valgrind @chux - Reinstate Monica

Comment: Tip: Code is very dense and reduces clarity.  Trim down.  e.g. `currentLine = (lineInText *) malloc(sizeof(lineInText));` --> `currentLine = malloc(sizeof *currentLine);` and `(*parsedCommand)->concatenatedExpression = (char *) malloc(sizeof(argv[indexOfExpressionArg])+1);
        strcpy((*parsedCommand)->concatenatedExpression, "");` to `(*parsedCommand)->concatenatedExpression = strdup(argv[indexOfExpressionArg]);`.  Add some vertical white-space.

Comment: In `buildArrayOfExpressionParts`, why do `parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts = NULL` just prior to allocating memory to that same struct member?

Comment: i wasn't sure why i'm getting this initialization errors from valgrind so i tried to initialize everything related to this struct, that is passed to updateConExpWithStr2() @SteveFriedl

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant but when i compile my program with gcc i get this warning:
 matchInLine.c: In function 'updateConExpWithStr1':
matchInLine.c:86:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   str1size = *orPtr - parsedCommand->arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2;

Comment: @NadavB - that kind of warning is virtually *always* relevant.

Comment: @Steve Friedl - so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Moving this from the comments to an Answer.

This code is exceptionally dense and is really hard to paste into a comment, so I've added some whitespace, and I see you've already removed unnecessary items such as casting the return of `malloc()`.

This is all about compiler warnings, including one you are *not* getting.

In general, compiler warnings are not things you **fix**, they are things you **understand**.  Once you understand what it's telling you, the fix is usually free and obvious.

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

The compiler is telling you that in the marked line below, one side is an integer and one side is a pointer - isn't it pretty clear what's going on here:

```
void updateConExpWithStr1(parsedCommandStruct parsedCommand,  char **endOfString,
                          int partIndex, char **orPtr, int *str1size) {

    *endOfString = parsedCommand.concatenatedExpression
                 + strlen(parsedCommand.concatenatedExpression);

    *orPtr = strstr(
      parsedCommand.arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2,
      "|");

    // THIS NEXT LINE IS WRONG
    str1size = *orPtr - parsedCommand.arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2;

    strncat(parsedCommand.concatenatedExpression, 
            parsedCommand.arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2,
            (size_t)str1size); // THIS LINE TOO
}
```

`str1size` is not a size, it's a *pointer* to a size, so this is all kinds of problematic.

The code as written stores an integer value where a pointer should be, and that means the caller is not seeing the size passed back. That's probably a bug.

Then the later line marked as a bug happens to function correctly even though it's two kinds of wrong. `strncat()` is expecting a size as the third parameter, but it's given a pointer cast to an integer, which is never the right thing for a size, except *this* time because the integer was improperly stored as a pointer. How about that!

But just adding a `*` only solves the technical problem, it's better to avoid this in the first place with good naming conventions.  What if your function had been:

```
void updateConExpWithStr1(parsedCommandStruct parsedCommand,  char **endOfString,
                          int partIndex, char **orPtr, int *pStr1size) {
    ...
    *pStr1size = blah // integral result

    strncat(parsedCommand.concatenatedExpression, 
            parsedCommand.arrayOfExpressionParts[partIndex].expressionPartInfo.str1OrStr2,
            *pStr1size);
}
```

Here we not only store the result properly, but by changing the name to remind you that it's a pointer, it makes it easier for you tell just by looking that this is not just an integral size.

---

**The lesson here**, I hope, is that you should take compiler warnings seriously with a goal of *understanding them*, not just making them go away.

When you put `(size_t) str1size` in the call to `strncat()`, I'm pretty confident you were doing this to silence a compiler warning that you didn't understand, and that's dangerous.

By adding the cast, you told the compiler "trust me", so this was a bug that went into hiding in plain sight (I didn't notice it until I was mostly done writing this post).

This is a discipline that all good C programmers develop: to crave compiler warnings, and to *understand* every one of them.  Always turn them on to the max, and **always** include them in any SO post.